# R plot with strings showing in the axis

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, vertical-text

I am plotting number of residents against the dorm room numbers (4 digits). The room numbers are supposed to be strings. But when I used as.character(RmNum), the axis still shows as numeric.

```
meanResidents = c(3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5)
rmNumber = c(2034, 3043, 4012, 2035, 2022, 3013)
plot(as.character(rmNumber), meanResidents, xlab = as.character(rmNumber))
```

I would want the dorm numbers showing vertically in the axis. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Please give us your code and a small dataset we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Roland meanResidents = c(3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5); rmNumber = c(2034, 3043, 4012, 2035, 2022, 3013).

Comment: @Roland My code is plot(as.character(rmNumber), meanResidents, xlab = as.character(rmNumber)) But the xaxis shows up numerics not strings.

Comment: I also tried plot(as.character(rmNumber), meanResidents, xlab ='n', xaxt = 'n'); axis(1, at=seq(1, length(rmNumber), 1), labels=as.character(rmNumber), las =2) it still doesn't work....

Answer (score 11):

With the function `axis` you can specify the position of the axis, where to put the tick marks (`at`) and choose the `labels`. The parameter `las=2` means labels perpendicular to the axis.

```
plot(meanResidents, axes=FALSE, xlab="dorms")
axis(2)
axis(1, at=seq_along(meanResidents),labels=as.character(rmNumber), las=2)
box()
```

[image: the plot]

Comment: @user2498497 If you're happy with the result (and you're not hoping for another answer), it's nice to indicate that by clicking the checkmark by this answer.