# Increase axis label space for string label values

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a plot where the x-axis contains strings. I followed the instructions from this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347991/r-plot-with-strings-showing-in-the-axis) and successfully created the following plot:

```
myDf <- cbind(Row.Names=rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
plot(myDf$mpg, axes=F, xlab="Car", ylab="MPG")
axis(2)
axis(1, at=seq_along(myDf$mpg), labels=myDf$Row.Names, las=2, cex.axis=0.70)
box()
```

[image]

Now, the problem is that the axis is very cramped. How do increase the vertical space between the x-axis and the bottom of the plot image? Ideally, the x-axis values would not overlap with the x-axis label ("Car" in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to set wider margins at the bottom. Then use *mtext()* to add the x-axis label.

```
# set the margins 
par(mar = c(10, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))

plot(myDf$mpg, axes=F, xlab="", ylab="MPG")
axis(2)
axis(1, at = seq_along(myDf$mpg), labels = myDf$Row.Names, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.70)
box()

# add xlabel, "line" arguement controls vertical position
mtext("Car", side = 1, line = 6)
```

[image]

Using *ggplot*:

```
library(ggplot2)
#my data
myDf <- cbind(car = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
#to keep ordering as in data, set custom levels (default is alphabetical)
myDf$car <- factor(myDf$car, levels = myDf$car)

#plot
ggplot(myDf, aes(x = car, y =  mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  # rotate car names by 90 degrees, adjust vertically and horizontally
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to determine the margins (and the text 'line' argument) programmatically rather than through trial and error?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I can't tell. Why not use ggplot?